# Cant require playwright

Tags: node.js, npm, playwright

trying to run the following snippet

```
const { it, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
 
it('is a basic test with the page', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  const home = await page.waitForSelector('home-navigation');
  expect(await home.innerText()).toBe(' Playwright');
});
```

but get the following error :

```
TypeError: test_runner_1.fixtures.defineParameter is not a function
```

pointing to my require statement, I have run npm i -D @playwright/test @playwright/test-runner and have the modules present. Why would this fail? trying to run it with node 'filename.js'

Comment: @playwright/test is under active development and the underlying API is changing. I would recommend waiting for an release/announcement.

Answer (score 1):

when you use [playwright-test](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-test) test runner:
run commands like with **npx**:

file should be store in format *.ts, like:

```
foo.spec.ts
```

Run all tests across Chromium, Firefox and WebKit

```
npx folio
```

Run tests on a single browser

```
npx folio --param browserName=chromium
```

Run all tests in headful mode

```
npx folio --param headful
```

Run tests with slowMo (slows down Playwright operations by n milliseconds)

```
npx folio --param slowMo=100
```

Save screenshots on failure in test-results directory

```
npx folio --param screenshotOnFailure
```

See all options

```
npx folio --help
```

to run your code with more than 1 param:

```
npx foo.spec.ts --param browserName=chromium --param headful
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for the Test scripts to run. It will look for the file name to be either `*.spec.ts` or `*.test.ts`